# Triggering event after load from several tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, ajax, json

I'm building a jquery/ajax application which reads data from several tables in a database using json.

I'd like to load all data when the document.ready event is triggered and then update the page content when this is complete.

I've got my head around using callbacks for individual tables but am not sure how to string several of these together ie. trigger the page update only when ALL data has loaded.

Eg. Document.Ready -> Request Table 1 & Table 2 -> When BOTH have been retrieved refresh page.

Is there a standard pattern for this type of approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a custom bound event / trigger, although you could. I would only do this if the event was element related.

You could do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var successCount = 0;

    function success(response, status){
        if(status == "success" && (++successCount == 2)) // 2 success completed 
            dataready(); // call dataready
    };

    function dataready(){
        alert('data ready')
    };

    $('#table1').load('/url/1', success);
    $('#table2').load('/url/2', success);
});
```